# How can I make the latin small letter a with cup over it?

Tags: symbols

I was just reading "Learning Segmentation by Random Walks" by "Marina Meila" and "Jianbo Shi".

How can I make the letter (or rather the diacritical mark above the a) in the last name of the first author? Is it a [caron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron)? If not, how is it called?

[image]

Comment: `\u{a}` is the command and you can replace `a` by other letter.

Comment: The character is used in the Romanian language. The diacritic is known as *breve* (Latin *brevis*, which means “short”). The TeX notation is `\u`

Comment: I would consider updating the image in the post not containing someone else's(?) email address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command is `\u{a}`.

Most of TeX editors can insert the commands from a toolbar or similar. For example, in TeXstudio you can see the left panel

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `xelatex`, you can directly input the characters with the accents.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
hăbĕo (hăbĕo, hăbes, habui, habitum, hăbēre)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, depending on how often/how much you want to do this, is to enter the character directly in your document (e.g. on Ubuntu with compose keys turned on, `(right ALT)-) a` produces ă, although I haven't got it working within Emacs yet!) and using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Whether this is worth it definitely depends on your OS and the frequency with which you need to do it - I just wasted 5 minutes trying to figure out how to insert ă on MacOS (supposedly it's `Command-B a`, but didn't work for me ...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Maliă
\end{document}
```

[image]